# Backbone.Paginator : cannot read property 'requestPager' why?

Tags: backbone.js, pagination, backbone.paginator

I downloaded the Backbone.Paginator production version. I went through the example, copied and pasted everything exactly the way it appears, but I keep getting cannot read property 'requestPager'. What am I doing wrong? I already made the reference to the backbone.paginator.min.js, what else do I need to do?

Thanks

EDIT:
If I remove paginator, my application works fine. It displays data without any issue.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was that I had referenced backbone.paginator after my collections. It's small things like these that I still have to get used to and be aware of.

Comment: It is also the reason why you should include the problematic code along side your question. We can't debug what we can't see.